# Extract data based on some field values from elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to retrieve data from elastic search. I indexed data in elastc search and it look like below

```
{
  "_index": "user",
  "_type": "user_type",
  "_id": "2393294",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 2,
  "_source": {
    "name": "shwn decker",
    "worksFor": {
      "legalName": "nykc private fund",
      "address": "Mk street, bruke field"
    },
  },
  "fields": {
    "tweetDate": [
      1457481600000
     ]
   },
   "sample_date":"10/10/2013"
 }
```

I want to search the data based on the field "name" and "legalName". I tried some queries but when I am trying to filter data based on both field then no document is getting matched. 
Query which I used is:

```
 curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/user/user_type/_search?pretty' -H 'Content- Type: application/json' -d'
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":{
             "query_string": {
                "query": "shwn decker",
             "fields": ["name"]
          }
         },
         "filter":{
            "term":{
                   "worksFor.legalName":"nykc private fund"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

What modification I should do in the query so that I can get the result. I am using customized mapping for this data which is shown below:

```
{
  "settings":
  {
    "number_of_shards" : 3,
    "number_of_replicas" : 2
  },
    "mappings" : {
      "user_type" : {
        "properties" : {
          "name" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
                  "raw" : {
                   "type":"keyword"
                   }
       }
          },
           "worksFor" : {
            "properties" : {
              "address" : {
                "type" : "text"
              },
              "legalName" : {
                "type" : "text",
                 "fields" : {
                  "raw" : {
                  "type":"keyword"
                   }
      }
              },
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }'
```

Comment: Which ES version you're using ?

Comment: 5.5 It support bool query

Comment: Did you define any mappings before indexing your data ?

Comment: Yes I defined the mapping for this data. I edited the question to include mapping also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you didn't define any mappings before indexing your data and all your fields are indexed as **text** which means that they are analyzed. It means that instead of

> nykc private fund

your index contains three separate words for this document under *worksFor.legalName* key.

Then you're trying to do [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-terms-query.html) filter which is not analyzed so in fact you're comparing entire phrase against single words. That's why you're getting no results. If you still want to do terms filtering you should define this field as [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/keyword.html).

So what you need to do is to remove your index, define mapping, at least for this one particular field and then index your data again. Here's how you can define mapping for your field

```
PUT localhost:9200/user

{
  "mappings": {
    "user_type": {
      "properties": {
        "worksFor.legalName": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then same query should return your document.

**EDIT**:
all above is still valid but question was edited and mapping definition has been attached. With such mapping there should be:

```
{
 "query":{
    "bool":{
       "must":{
           "query_string": {
              "query": "shwn decker",
           "fields": ["name"]
        }
       },
       "filter":{
          "term":{
                 "worksFor.legalName.raw":"nykc private fund"
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

}

It's because **raw** part of legalName is a keyword.

Comment: but I am already defining the 'legalName' as a keyword type in my mapping.You can check the mapping above.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, the problem is that you have multifield mapping and legalName is still text. My example still works however if you want to use your mapping you should redefine your filter key to worksFor.legalName.raw since raw part is a keyword.

Comment: Thanks @mickl, I redefine the filter with worksFor.legalName.raw and it works. :)